# Getting the size of a remote file in bytes? (without content-size)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl, wget

I'd like to get the byte size of a remote file as simply as possible.

The issue is that many servers don't send the `content-size` parameter in their headers these days

`curl -I`, `wget --spider` and `wget --server-response` all give me detailed headers, but nothing about the size of the content.

```
curl -Is https://wordpress.com | grep content
```

only returns this:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

So I guess I could work around it like so:

```
curl -s https://wordpress.com/ > /tmp/foo; du /tmp/foo | awk '{print $1}'
```

And it *does work*. But I think it's a little ridiculous that I'm downloading the file itself and writing to my machine.

I imagine there's a better way, where something like `curl` can get the file size directly from memory, or just get the length of the output to bash in bytes.

Comment: what about `curl -X HEAD -i ...`?

Comment: in any case you'd think you could download the file but discard it instead of saving it to disk or ram, just increment a size counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-size header is not guaranteed in every response. So best you can do might be, to use `content-size` if available and if not, call `curl` to download and assess the size of the remote content:

```
curl -sL 'https://wordpress.com'  --write-out '%{size_download}\n' --output /dev/null
```

Comment: This is great, was not familiar with `write-out`